# Exclude symbols from Regular Expressions [PHP]

Tags: php

I'm new to programming, i'm starting with PHP and trying to use regular expressions to exclude symbols from a string and check the maximum length to be 16 characters.

This is what i've done by now:

```
<php
if(!preg_match("/^[^\!\¡\-\"\#\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\¿\_\,\.\~\<\>\\\[\]\{\}\+\*\;\:\@\¬\=\°\^]{0,16}/", $Sname))
    {
      $Error = '<span class="label error"> Invalid name. </span>';
    }
?>
```

I've been using regex101 to 'validate' this regex and it is supposed to work (I mean, i've testing with strings in the web and worked as intended) . the original string that i got from the page was

```
^[^!¡\-"#$%&\/()=?¿_,.~<>\[\]{}+*;:@¬=°\^]{0,16}
```

Whoever, this didn't work in the code, it always show 'Invalid Name' even though the string it's supposed to be valid. I'm kinda lost right now. Any ideas?

Sorry for the ignorance
Thanks in advice!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if with no symbols you mean only letters, digits and space this could be the right regex: `^[a-zA-Z\d\s]{1,16}$` so you can do something like this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\d\s]{1,16}$/', $target)) {
   // do something
}
```

**Edit**

Usually is a bad idea to allow accented characters because you can easily face encoding problems when for example you store and retrieve something from/to a database. Another bad habit is to think a regex from subtraction, don't think on what a string don't need but what it needs and i'll give you an example to deal with accented characters but not with special characters. What you may looking for is:

```
if (preg_match('/^[^!£$%\'()=]{1,16}$/', $target)) {
       // do something
    }
```

But what if i miss some symbols? There are thousands of symbols that could be used to bypass this simple regex, no one for the previous one.

Comment: I also need accented characters

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, i'll have that in mind
Cheers!